# Convert screen from portrait to landscape it does not keep it landscape while rotate it left to right and vice-varsa

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4, landscape-portrait

i did change orientation of uidevice as per screen requirement.

For example screen A
Which i need to make portrait only.

Screen B
It should be landscape and i did it.

But after going back to screen A and again i go to screen B and rotate device left to right or right to left screen B's orientation changes to portrait.

Please comment if anyone have solution for this.

Here i will explain whole scenario what i am doing in my project:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait   //Defined variable for orientation

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return shouldRotate ? .allButUpsideDown : .portrait
}
```

**In class A**

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        Global.appDelegate.shouldRotate = false
    }
```

**In class B**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}
Global.appDelegate.shouldRotate = false
```

**Now i tried to make B screen landscape in all rotation, for that i tried method below:**

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil, completion: {
        _ in
        if UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait || UIDevice.current.orientation == .portraitUpsideDown {
            //                Global.AppUtility.lockOrientation(.landscape)
            let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
            UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
            Global.appDelegate.shouldRotate = true
        }
    })

}
```

But this method works first time only, after selecting A and again i go to screen B it keep it portrait.

Comment: Please upload some code of what you're doing.

Comment: @Biclops thanks for your response, i have edited my question with code. Please let me know if you have any feasible solution.